# How to get the value to this method

Tags: java

I have a project working with database, I have some main classes like student, module, enrolment and more 3 class to manage them. The problem in here is that

In the class Student I have this code

private String id;

```
@DomainConstraint(optional = false, mutable = true, type = Type.String, length = 50)
private String name;

@DomainConstraint(optional = false, mutable = true, type = Type.String, length = 20)
private String dob;

@DomainConstraint(optional = false, mutable = true, type = Type.String, length = 50)
private String address;

@DomainConstraint(optional = false, mutable = true, type = Type.String, length = 50)
private String email;

private static int autoIncrementInt = 0;

public Student(String name, String dob, String address, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
    idGenerator();
}
```

But in class EnrolmentManager, I want to take the name of student to enrol them to courses like this

```
public void load() throws SQLException {
    Connection con;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    // set up properties, e.g. user name/password
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:courseman;create=false", connectionProps);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Student.name as studentName, Module.name as Modulename, Enrolment.internalMark,Enrolment.examMark FROM Student,Module,Enrolment WHERE Student.id=Enrolment.sid AND Module.code=Enrolment.mcode");

    while (rs.next()) {
        String s = rs.getString("studentName");
        String m = rs.getString("Modulename");
        double y = rs.getDouble("internalMark");
        double d = rs.getDouble("examMark");
        Enrolment e = new Enrolment( s, m, y, d);
        enrolments.add(e);
    }
}
```

An error in here because in class Enrolment I have its Constructor is

```
public Enrolment(Student stu, Module module,Double internalMark, Double examMark) {
    this.student = stu;
    this.module = module;
    this.internalMark = internalMark;
    this.examMark = examMark;
    finalGradeGenerator();
}
```

therefore in class `EnrolmentManager`, it have an error is the constructor Enrolment is undifined. Can you solve this problem for me, thank you

Comment: can we see the Enrolment class code?

Answer (score 1):

Enrolment class constructor is expecting `Student`(`stu`) & `Module` objects (`module`) as parameters, however you are parsing them as `String` objects.

Comment: And it expects an instance of student to

Answer (score 0):

It is because your enrollment class is expecting Module and Student as parameters you are giving 2 Strings .

//below is actual constructor

```
public Enrolment(Student stu, Module module,Double internalMark, Double examMark)
```

but you are passing as

```
public Enrolment(String stu, String module,Double internalMark, Double examMark)
```

Comment: He actually passes Enrolment(String, String, double, double)